# Jquery issue in browser XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest

Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.

We tried to append timeline jquery file like below this, with HTML (Injecting data dynamically so) but I getting this "Synchronous issue". Is there any way to append the timeline library in Html!

```
     var contentli = '<script async="async" src="/assets/js/timeline/horizontal_timeline.min.js" ><\/script><script>$("#example").horizontalTimeline({dateDisplay: "monthYear",useFontAwesomeIcons: true,});<\/script> <div class="cd-horizontal-timeline" id="example"><div class="events-content"><ol>';
  contentli += '</ol></div></div>';
  $("#timelineH").empty();
  $( contentli ).insertAfter( "#timelineH" );
```

Comment: The question doesn't really have anything to with Firestore, so I removed the tag.

Comment: i dont see where you're doing your XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 1):

When jQuery inserts HTML that contains a `<script>` tag that loads an external script, it turns that into a synchronous AJAX request to read the file, and then calls `eval()` to execute it. This is triggering the deprecation warning.

You can use `$.getScript()` to load a script asynchronously, and then execute a callback when it finishes loading.

```
$.getScript("/assets/js/timeline/horizontal_timeline.min.js", function() {
    $("#timelineH").html('<div class="cd-horizontal-timeline" id="example"><div class="events-content"><ol></ol></div></div>');
    $("#example").horizontalTimeline({dateDisplay: "monthYear",useFontAwesomeIcons: true,});
});
```